# macos: binding command-plus and command-minus to text-scale-increase and text-scale-decrease

Tags: osx

Emacs 26.1: `C-h v` tells me that command-"+" is "s-+".  how do I then define a properly working `(global-set-key "s-+" 'text-scale-increase)` ?

Answer (score 1):

What does `C-h k s-+` says? In my case in Emacs 27.0.50:

> `s-+` runs the command `text-scale-adjust` (found in global-map), which is
>   an autoloaded interactive Lisp function in `face-remap.el`.
>
> It is bound to `s-0`, `s-=`, `s-+`, `s--`, `C-x C-0`, `C-x C-=`, `C-x C--`, `C-x C-+`.

Adjusting text scale with `s-<+|=|-|0>` is working out of the box since [this commit](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/lisp/term/ns-win.el?id=fb8d2e064dff0dbbe71809b2ee4184fe44805258).

Answer (score 0):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "s-+") 'text-scale-increase)
(global-set-key (kbd "s--") 'text-scale-decrease)
(global-set-key (kbd "s-_") 'text-scale-decrease)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?